# Why won't my for loop write to all files created?

Tags: python-3.x

I think there's a problem with my for loop or open with statement, but I'm unsure as to what it is.

I'm attempting to compare each item to each line of a text file, and if the line contains the item, the line is printed to a .bed file with the name taken from the accession number (acc).

```
    for acc in acc_trimmed:
        f2 = open((acc.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".bed", "w")
        print("_____________________")
        for line in f:
            if acc in line:
                print(line)
                f2.write(line)
        f2.close()
```

I am expecting each file to be created (with the file name taken from acc), but only the first file is both created and written to. All other files are created but not written to.

The console output is:

```
____________________
chr10   75911036    75911101    NM_006721.3_cds_0_0_chr10_75911037_f    0   +

chr10   75960521    75960596    NM_006721.3_cds_1_0_chr10_75960522_f    0   +

chr10   75984295    75984349    NM_006721.3_cds_2_0_chr10_75984296_f    0   +

chr10   76074424    76074503    NM_006721.3_cds_3_0_chr10_76074425_f    0   +

chr10   76153898    76154071    NM_006721.3_cds_4_0_chr10_76153899_f    0   +

chr10   76158228    76158337    NM_006721.3_cds_5_0_chr10_76158229_f    0   +

chr10   76285013    76285184    NM_006721.3_cds_6_0_chr10_76285014_f    0   +

chr10   76349039    76349075    NM_006721.3_cds_7_0_chr10_76349040_f    0   +

chr10   76360136    76360251    NM_006721.3_cds_8_0_chr10_76360137_f    0   +

chr10   76429940    76430027    NM_006721.3_cds_9_0_chr10_76429941_f    0   +

chr10   76468078    76468203    NM_006721.3_cds_10_0_chr10_76468079_f   0   +

_____________________
_____________________
_____________________
_____________________
_____________________
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a specific reason this is happening. However, I recommend using the `with` keyword for your file IO:

```
for acc in acc_trimmed:
    with open((acc.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".bed", "w") as output_file:
        print("_____________________")
        for line in f:
            if acc in line:
                print(line)
                output_file.write(line)
```

It'll handle the opening/closing of the file, in case this is where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! It still threw up the same issue, however this seems to fix it:

```
for acc in acc_trimmed:
    with open("RefSeq_CDS") as f:
        with open((acc.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".bed", "w") as output_file:
            print("_____________________")
            for line in f:
                if acc in line:
                    print(line)
                    output_file.write(line)
```